# AWS locate PHP files/script like what we do in wamp server for android access

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, wampserver

Currently, I am using wamp server in localhost for android communication. Now, I would like to deploy the whole app into AWS.

However, how to do locate the php files like what I did in wamp server (put the files/script inside www directory)

Comment: depends on how you set up your server on aws. And we dont know that.

Comment: could you give an example on how it is setup

Comment: No, could you give an example of the setup! Do you have a `htdocs` folder?

Comment: Sry I am new to AWS, where does that htdocs folder located? Currently I am throwing my asp.net to elastic beanstalk, and my node app to s3.